# how to redirect into 9apps apk using any application link from gapps

Tags: android, android-intent

i want to redirect directly into 9apps using [this link](https://mx-player.en.9apps.com/) and then 9apps display applcation which is takes from above link is it possible like

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setPackage("com.mobile.indiaapp");
            i.setData(Uri.parse("https://mx-player.en.9apps.com/");
            context.startActivity(i
            );
```

please help me

Comment: Your code will open link in browser

Answer (score 0):

**If your calling it from activity**

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://mx-player.en.9apps.com/"));
                    startActivity(i);
```

**and from other**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://mx-player.en.9apps.com/"));
                    context.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.package");
context.startActivity(launchIntent);
```